# .NET dependency copy causing large build size

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll

I am bin deploying a large dll and it is causing the final build to be huge.

So I have ProjectA which references ProjectB, which references a third party DLL.
this third party DLL is now in both project bin folders even though it is only directly referenced by ProjectB. The problem is that this third party dll is massive, and causes the final build to be huge since it is copied to so many bin folders. I am really just looking for a best practice in this situation.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Is this a web project or a windows project? I really don't understand the issue because normally when you deploy an application, there is a single executable alongside its DLL dependencies. In other words, a "Project" will compile into an assembly, which is then deployed. "Projects" are not deployed themselves, only the assemblies are.

Comment: This is several web projects that consume several library projects that use this large dll. Im not talking as much about deployment as I am the build taking up lots of room on both developer machines and build machines. So we might have a data access class that references this large dll that is meant for DB connections. Then, the data access class is referenced in a web project. Now, the large dll is copied to both the data access class and the web project bin folders.

Comment: Because ProjectA references ProjectB, that means you have ProjectB copied to ProjectA's bin folder, which means that ProjectB needs the large DLL in order to correctly be loaded... thus it has to exist in both.  A doesn't reference C, but it does reference B and B references C, otherwise A would not be able to load the B assembly.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch thats what I thought :(... was hoping there was some magic bullet but that appears to not be the case.

Comment: You might be able to perform a clean on Project B after you have built Project A, but that would mean having to completely rebuild B each time.

Answer (score 0):

Since your 3rd party DLL is large and is shared between multiple applications, a solution could be to put the shared DLL into the [global assembly cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6axd4fx6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of deploying it in each application.

This will only work if the DLL is strong-named, but many companies strong-name their assemblies so you might give it a try.

The idea is that you can drag and drop this 1 DLL into the GAC, and then you can continue bin deploying the rest of the application without this file. As long as you put the DLL in the right GAC (framework version and bitness) and compile the application against the dependency, the .NET framework will find it in the GAC, so there is no need to include it with each deployment.

Comment: He said he's bin deploying, which would assume he doesn't want to use GAC for anything.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - Okay, can you think of another way to share a huge DLL between projects?

Comment: Thats correct, we used to have the oracle client installed on our app servers (the dll is an oracle runtime lib), but we can not longer do this, so we have to bin deploy. Unfortunately we have some bad design in place so we have tons of projects with direct oracle references and then tons of projects referencing those projects. I am trying to figure out a way to reduce the number of bins this is copied to without breaking the code and without having to do a major rewrite. Not sure its possible, thought I'd ask here to see if there was something I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

The primary cause, as far as I can tell, is that you've set this reference to "Copy Local", causing it to be duplicated between the projects in the first place. If you'd add the reference to each project normally and only set it to copy local for the web project, the number of copies would already be drastically reduced.